# How to connect to VSCode container locally using ssh?

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, ssh, dockerfile, vscode-remote

Using [VSCode Dev Container](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers), I would like to be able to `ssh` from within my container to inside my container (for testing purposes).

```sh
ssh root@localhost
```

I have read many articles and similar questions, but I am unable to create a minimal functional example.

My `Dockerfile` is as follow:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends net-tools iputils-ping openssh-client openssh-server 


RUN mkdir /var/run/sshd
RUN echo 'root:screencast' | chpasswd
RUN sed -i 's/PermitRootLogin prohibit-password/PermitRootLogin yes/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config

# SSH login fix. Otherwise user is kicked off after login
RUN sed 's@session\s*required\s*pam_loginuid.so@session optional pam_loginuid.so@g' -i /etc/pam.d/sshd

ENV NOTVISIBLE "in users profile"
RUN echo "export VISIBLE=now" >> /etc/profile

EXPOSE 22
CMD ["/usr/sbin/sshd", "-D"]
```

My `devcontainer.json` is as follow:

```json
{
    "name": "Ubuntu",
    "build": {
        "dockerfile": "Dockerfile",
    },
    "settings": {
        "terminal.integrated.shell.linux": "/bin/bash"
    },
    "extensions": [],
    "forwardPorts": [
        22
    ],
    "appPort": 22,
    "runArgs": [
        "--net",
        "host",
        "-p",
        "22:22"
    ]
}
```

I tested multiple combinations of parameters (`forwardPorts`, `appPort`, `EXPOSE`, etc.) but every time either:

- the `ssh` connection is refused
- I connect to my host and not to my container

Do you know how could I modify these files in order to be able to connect with `ssh` from the container's bash interpreter please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several issues to address:

1. Since your host is using port 22 you have to use another one. You can do this with `appPort`:

```json
    "appPort": "2222:22",
```

This notation maps host's port 2222 to container's 22.

2. `runArgs` and `forwardPorts` are redundant.
3. You need to add `"overrideCommand": false` to prevent VSCode overriding `CMD` declared in the Dockerfile.
4. Your `sed` in Dockerfile is incorrect, default config does not contain a line `PermitRootLogin prohibit-password` but it contains `#PermitRootLogin <some-other-value`. Change `sed` command to this:

```
RUN sed -i 's/.*PermitRootLogin.*/PermitRootLogin yes/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

And here are modified files for convenience:

**Dockerfile**:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends net-tools iputils-ping openssh-client openssh-server 


RUN mkdir /var/run/sshd
RUN echo 'root:test' | chpasswd
RUN sed -i 's/.*PermitRootLogin.*/PermitRootLogin yes/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config

# SSH login fix. Otherwise user is kicked off after login
RUN sed 's@session\s*required\s*pam_loginuid.so@session optional pam_loginuid.so@g' -i /etc/pam.d/sshd

ENV NOTVISIBLE "in users profile"
RUN echo "export VISIBLE=now" >> /etc/profile

EXPOSE 22
CMD ["/usr/sbin/sshd", "-D"]
```

**devcontainer.json**:

```json
{
    "name": "Ubuntu",
    "build": {
        "dockerfile": "Dockerfile",
    },
    "settings": {
        "terminal.integrated.shell.linux": "/bin/bash"
    },
    "extensions": [],
    "appPort": "2222:22",
    "overrideCommand": false
}
```

When you run the container you can connect to it with `ssh root@localhost -p 2222` and password 'test'.

Also, I don't know why you decided to go with VSCode specific way to Docker, maybe there is a solid reason to do this, but there is a better way. You can use [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) to create a testing environment. It is:

- better documented;
- widely used;
- supported by many IDE's (including VSCode).

Take a look at this `docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
# Check out this reference https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/
# for list of available versions, their differences, and the file format in general.
version: "3.0"

# This is where you declare containers you want to run.
services:

  # This is the name of the service. One cool thing about it is that is will be a DNS name
  # in the networks where this service will be present. So when you need to connect this
  # service from another container you can simply do 'ssh username@ssh-server'.
  ssh-server:

    # This is the name of the image to use. In this case I intentionally used a nonexistent name.
    # Because of that when Docker will build the image from the Dockerfile, it will assign this
    # name to the image. This is not required since I've added 'build' property but giving the
    # right name could come handy.
    image: myssh

    # This is equivalent to 'build an image from the Dockerfile in current working directory' or
    # 'docker build .'
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile

    # This maps host's port 2222 to container's 22. This isn't necessary unless you want to connect
    # to this container from outside (e.g. from host or another machine). Containers do not
    # require 'exposure' or any other step to reach one another within one network - they have all
    # ports open. That is why it is called port forwarding or mapping.
    ports:
      - "2222:22"

  # Same image as the server but with a different command to execute.
  ssh-client:
    image: myssh
    build:
      context: .
    # Just a loop to run a command every second. Won't work with password, you need a key or some hacks.
    command: bash -c 'while sleep 1; do ssh root@ssh-server ls /; done'
```

If you save it to a directory with the `Dockerfile` above, you can run it with `docker-compose up`. Or you can integrate it with VSCode: when there is no `.devcontainer` directory and you click `Reopen in container`, you can select `From 'docker-compose.yml'`, then select one of the services you want and it will build and start a container. It will also create `.devcontainer` directory with `devcontainer.json` in it.

Comment: Thanks for your help and thanks for having edited your answer with even more valuable information! I used `devcontainer` this way as a first introduction to Docker. I will definitely take a closer look at `docker-compose`.

I also noticed you removed the `--net host` in `"runArgs"`. Indeed, if it is present then VSCode reports an error while building the container: `Error response from daemon: Container xxx is not running`. Could you briefly explain me the problem with this argument, please?

Comment: I probably wouldn't explain it better than the documentation does: `If you use the host network mode for a container, that container’s network stack is not isolated from the Docker host (the container shares the host’s networking namespace), and the container does not get its own IP-address allocated. For instance, if you run a container which binds to port 80 and you use host networking, the container’s application is available on port 80 on the host’s IP address.`

So you had a conflict because your host was using port 22 and you container was unable to bind it.